# Geometry ratio problem

Tags: geometry

> The other sharp angle of a right triangle is $30$ degrees. A line is drawn on the midpoint of the hypotenuse as shown in the figure. Calculate the ratio of the lengths of the two parts for which the line divides the leg.

[image]

Any tips on how to proceed? I'm relatively bad at geometry...

Answer (score 1):

> Problem : Given $AD=DB$ and $DE$ perpendicular to $AB$ and angle $A=30^{\circ}$ find $\frac{AE}{EC}$.

[image]

Draw line EB. Angle EBD = angle EAD = angle EBC, and AD = DB = BC. Therefore triangles ADE, BDE, BCE are congruent with each other and similar to triangle ACB. Hence EC = ED and
$$\frac{AE}{EC}=\frac{AE}{ED}=\frac{AB}{BC}=2$$

Comment: I like this answer specifically. It's one of the things you can teach that are almost obvious

Answer (score 0):

Let $h $ the lenght of the hypotenuse and $a,b$ the lengt of the two parts of the legs, so we have:
$$a=\frac{\frac{h}{2}}{\cos(\pi/6)}=\frac{h}{\sqrt3}$$
and
$$b=h\cos(\pi/6)-a=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}h-\frac{\sqrt3h}{3}=\frac{(3\sqrt3-2\sqrt3)h}{6}=\frac{\sqrt3h}{6}$$
The ratio is:
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{6}{\sqrt3\cdot\sqrt3}=\frac{6}{3}=2$$

Comment: @Viktor: if this anser has been useful, mybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?